# regex между первым и последним совпадением \n

Tags: python, python-3.x, регулярные-выражения

Есть строка, нужно вытащить все, что между первым и последним \n
(между крайними '\n' могут стоять ЛЮБЫЕ символы, включая такую же подстроку '\n'; '\n' - текст, не перевод строки):

```
x= r'text text\nФотография\nhttps://blabla.jpg\n\n3 textxtext\n'
pattern = r'\n[^\n]*\n$' # мой вариант вытаскивает предпоследнее-последнее включение
re.findall(pattern, x)

# нужно
> r'Фотография\nhttps://blabla.jpg\n\n3 textxtext'
```

Comment: `[а-яА-Я].*[^\\n]` https://regex101.com/r/d4BTPV/2

Comment: `\n` в строке - это символ или текст?

Comment: \n в строке - текст

Comment: @Qwertiy , если искать вашей формулой в x1 = 'Карлукрал коралы\nЗапись на стене\n' , то уже неверно ищет

Comment: @Evv, я не писал никаких формул.

Comment: @Evv я предложил вариант исходя из требований в вопросе: "# нужно
> 'Фотография\nhttps://blabla.jpg\n\n3 textxtext'"

Comment: @Qwertiy, дико извиняюсь, я неправильно тэгнул )

Comment: Я не достаточно точно сформулировал требования. Уточняю:
между крайними '\n' могут стять любые символы, включая такую же подстроку '\n'

Comment: `'\\n'.join(s.split('\\n')[1:-1])`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вот так вот:

```
(?<=\\n).*(?=\\n)
```

Тест https://regex101.com/r/wdTC8g/1/

```
text text\nФотография\nhttps://blabla.jpg\n\n3 textxtext\n
\n42\n
\n123\n\n\n\n123\n
\n
42
```

Сгенерированный код:

```py
# coding=utf8
# the above tag defines encoding for this document and is for Python 2.x compatibility

import re

regex = r"(?<=\\n).*(?=\\n)"

test_str = ("text text\\nФотография\\nhttps://blabla.jpg\\n\\n3 textxtext\\n\n"
    "\\n42\\n\n"
    "\\n123\\n\\n\\n\\n123\\n\n"
    "\\n\n"
    "42\n")

matches = re.finditer(regex, test_str, re.MULTILINE)

for matchNum, match in enumerate(matches, start=1):

    print ("Match {matchNum} was found at {start}-{end}: {match}".format(matchNum = matchNum, start = match.start(), end = match.end(), match = match.group()))

    for groupNum in range(0, len(match.groups())):
        groupNum = groupNum + 1

        print ("Group {groupNum} found at {start}-{end}: {group}".format(groupNum = groupNum, start = match.start(groupNum), end = match.end(groupNum), group = match.group(groupNum)))

# Note: for Python 2.7 compatibility, use ur"" to prefix the regex and u"" to prefix the test string and substitution.
```

Answer (score 2):

Если переводов строки в искомом тексте может быть сколько угодно, то я предлагаю вместо того, чтобы городить огород, сделать такой костыль:

```
x = 'text text\nФотография\nhttps://blabla.jpg\n\n3 textxtext\n'
x1 = 'Карлукрал коралы\nЗапись на стене\n'

pattern = r"\n(.*)"
print(r"\n".join(re.findall(pattern, x.rstrip()))) # Фотография\nhttps://blabla.jpg\n\n3 textxtext
print(r"\n".join(re.findall(pattern, x1.rstrip())))# Запись на стене
```

Answer (score 1):

```py
text_1 = r'text text\nФотография\nhttps://blabla.jpg\n\n3 textxtext\n'

print(re.sub(r'^.*?\\n(.+)\\n.*$', r'\1', text_1))

# Фотография\nhttps://blabla.jpg\n\n3 textxtext
```

Если бы речь шла о `\n` как о переводе строки, то можно слегка поправить регулярку

```py
print(re.sub(r'^.*?\n(.+)\n.*$', r'\1', text_1, flags=re.S))
```